# Unable to use Rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Why I try to load Rpy2 in Python, the interpreter finds the module but as soon as I try to import anything from it, it returns an error:

e.g.

```
import rpy2 # No errors, although it does not print anything
```

But

```
import rpy2.robjects
```

returns the following error:

> /home/jimmy/.python_easy_install/rpy2-2.3.0beta1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so:
>   undefined symbol: Rf_translateCha rUTF8

---

I followed the instructions in the website:

**1.** Installed R with the option for shared libraries:

```
# <go to the R source directory>
make distclean
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make
make install
```

**2.** Added this to my `.bashhrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$RHOME/lib
```

**3.** And then installed `rpy2` with `easy_install` (I also tried with `pip`):

```
easy_install -d /home/jimmy/.python_easy_install rpy2
```

Why is it not working?

This is all on Linux with the latest versions of `Rpy2`, `R` and `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because an older version of R is picked up at runtime.

I'd think that a better way to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH would be to do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried this, and this was not the problem (the problem persists). Also, I did not have any other R paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I still that the problem is linked to something around stale libraries. I am developing under Linux 64 bits, Python 2.7 and 3.3 - R-2.15, and it is definitely working here (although I am using pip). Try to `pip uninstall rpy2` as many times are necessary (until all versions have been uninstalled) and run `pip install rpy2`